# ruby special match variables confusion

Tags: ruby

This code produces the expected result:

```
  def test_sub_is_like_find_and_replace
    assert_equal "one t-three", "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }
  end
```

I understand that `$1` is a variable for the first match, but I am not clear what the `[0,1]` is, or why it takes out the last two letters of `"two"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[0,1]` can be applied to any string to find  1 character starting at index position 0:

```
>> "Hello"[0,1]
=> "H"
```

Just for fun, something other than 0 and 1:

```
>> "Hello World"[3,5]
=> "lo Wo"
```

Starts at index position 3, takes 5 characters.

In your case

```
"two"[0, 1]
```

you take one character at index 0, namely "t".  It *looks* like it removed the last two characters; in reality it *produced* only the first.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the [`String.[]` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), in particular:

```
str[start, length] → new_str or nil
```

So, `$1[0, 1]` means, "slice the string returning from character at index 0 to index 0 + `1`."